# Android socket receive data

Tags: android, sockets, inputstream

I am new with android development so if any further information needed plz ask... I am trying to use sockets to send coordinates to server, receive query results and "Toast" them.
Until now in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();     

}
      ...

 class ClientThread implements Runnable {
             @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
             public void run() {
                 try {
                     InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                     socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                 } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e1) {
                     e1.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }


      public void onClickk(View view) {
             try {
                // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);............here some more code regarding coordinates. ............
```

And I am writing through the socket the coordinates (in the same method):

```
                        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                        if (lat!=null){

                            String json = "";

                            // 3. build jsonObject
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                            try {
                                jsonObject.accumulate("lat", lat);
                                jsonObject.accumulate("lon", lon);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
                            json = jsonObject.toString();

                         PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                 new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                 true);
                         out.println(json);
```

How I can receive data sent from the server? I am not sure how to use the InputSteam.

UPDATE: My server. WHen a message is received from the app the server tries to write a string on the socket.

```
       sock.on('data', function(data) {

          console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ': ' + data);

          sock.write(la);
       });

       });
```

Comment: What protocol server use? Anything other than http?

Comment: I am using the java.net.Socket library. Hope this helps

Comment: I don't mean android app, Your server is a java program?

Comment: No, It is an expresse application, nodejs

Comment: Your code is good then, get the inputstream from the socket, wrap it in a reader like datainputstream and read the incoming data.

Comment: Ali thank you for your help! Where exactly in the code I should do that? Because I tried this in the end of my code but for some reason when I push the button that triggers the onclickk method the button get stack and nothing happens. Do I have to initiate another thread or something?

Comment: You must do all the socket related task inside thread. I will answer the question along some codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Client extends Thread {

    public void run()
    {
         try
         {
              Socket socket = new Socket(address, PORT);
              PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
              out.println(json);
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
              String response = in.readLine()
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              socket.close();
         }
         catch(Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Ali I seems the right way ..but still not getting the toast notification

Comment: @gematzab do you receive data? do you send it in the server? Socket programming is very tricky. more tricker when each side is on different platform.

Comment: I updated the question. Yes, I can see that coordinates are received  on the node server side. Though I cant see if the data are received from the app. (also I ll mark your response as an answer, I think this is the right way even if I cant make it work)

Comment: @gematzab To get it working, don't write all the code. It brings a lot of confusion. I suggest starting with a simple code like mine that just send a byte of data and receive one byte as well. Log the received data on both side so you can be sure that everything is just fine.

Comment: Toast to work must be called on UI thread !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and finally find in here:

https://community.particle.io/t/using-tcp-to-communicate-between-an-android-and-photon-without-cloud-connection/28495/4

> `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //    private ListView mList;
//    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
//    private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private TCPClient mTcpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connectBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // connect to the server
                TCPClient.buttonPushed = "Kamran Gasimov, hi";
                new connectTask().execute("");
            }
        });



    }

    public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

        @Override
        protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object and
            mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                    Log.d("Message", message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Log.d("values", values[0]);
            //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
//            arrayList.add(values[0]);
            // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
            // from server was added to the list
//            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

> `TCPClient.java`

```
public class TCPClient {

    private String serverMessage;
    public static String buttonPushed;
    public static final String SERVERIP = "192.168.1.100"; //your Photon (formerly computer) IP address

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 7777;
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    private boolean mRun = false;

    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedWriter out1;
    OutputStreamWriter out2;
    OutputStream out3;
    BufferedReader in;

    /**
     *  Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message){
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            Log.d("TCP Client", "Message: " + message);
            out.flush();
        }
    }

    public void stopClient(){
        mRun = false;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            try {
                //send the message to the server

                out3 = socket.getOutputStream();
                out2 = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                out1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out3 = " + out3);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out2 = " + out2);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out1 = " + out1);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: out0 = " + out);

                sendMessage(buttonPushed); //this was the key
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Sent.");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Done.");

                //receive the message which the server sends back
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: received = " + in);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);
                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {
                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: I got to the while loop!");

                    serverMessage = in.readLine();

                    Log.e("TCP Client", "C: serverMessage = " + serverMessage);
                    new TCPClient(mMessageListener);
                    stopClient();
                    if (serverMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(serverMessage);
                    } else {
                        serverMessage = null;
                    }
                }

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: run = " + mRun);

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + serverMessage + "'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
                Log.d("TCP Client", "Socket closed.");
                serverMessage = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);
        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }
}
```